# how to handle NoSuchElementException in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception, testng, assertion

There is one scenario which I want to test.

There is a form with some mandatory fields and submit button.
[image]

- So in the image forename error is displayed because I have not filled
  it and clicked on submit button.
- But email is also a mandatory field, its not showing the error as I have filled it.

I want to verify here if the "email is required" error gone after filling the email field.

-I have used soft assertion to validate if errors are gone. My test cases are getting executed and showing pass. but in console it is showing NoSuchElementException.
I used try catch block to handle this exception but it is not going in catch block so not able to catch it.

```
softAssert.assertNull(cp.getForeNameError(),
            "Error messages do not dissapear on forename entry");
    softAssert.assertNull(cp.getEmailIdError(),
            "Error messages do not dissapear on emailid entry");
```

`console error : Error occured while creating elementBy.id: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #email-err

Comment: Please show us a code example... Without code, people can just guess what's happening and guesses are not that valuable when debugging a program.

Comment: @Tester, can you teach me getting web elements properties from picture?

Comment: Why this post has been closed when  have already provided the information which is needed to understand this problem. ??

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you are missing a delay / wait before accessing the element so that you trying to find the element before it exists on the page.
Or the element is inside an iframe.
Or you are using a wrong locator.
You don't show here your code, so we can not say what is going in your specific case.